# Immutable borrows inside mutable borrow

Tags: image, rust, mutable

I'm trying to get access to other pixels data while looping over those pixels.

```
extern crate image; // 0.19.0

const IMG_H: u32 = 10;
const IMG_W: u32 = 10;

fn foo(imgbuf: &mut image::ImageBuffer<image::Luma<u8>, Vec<u8>>, points: &Vec<u16>) {
    for (_x, _y, pixel) in imgbuf.enumerate_pixels_mut() {
        for p in points {
            let x2 = *p as u32 / IMG_H;
            let y2 = *p as u32 % IMG_W;
            let i = imgbuf.get_pixel(x2, y2)[0];
            *pixel = image::Luma([i]);
        }
    }
}
```

I get this error:

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `*imgbuf` as immutable because it is also borrowed as mutable
  --> src/lib.rs:11:21
   |
7  |     for (_x, _y, pixel) in imgbuf.enumerate_pixels_mut() {
   |                            ------                      - mutable borrow ends here
   |                            |
   |                            mutable borrow occurs here
...
11 |             let i = imgbuf.get_pixel(x2, y2)[0];
   |                     ^^^^^^ immutable borrow occurs here
```

Is there another solution than duplicating the image buffer to get an access to certain values?

Comment: It may help (in this example) to remove `_mut` from `enumerate_pixels_mut()`, because you don't need mutable access, but this is propaly due the lack of a MCVE ;)

Comment: MCVE added, and I indeed need a mutable access to the pixel !

Comment: This is **not** an MCVE. If I put this straight into my rust compiler, it won't compile.  where does `ImageBuffer` come from? What is the external crate?
In short, you can't get the pixel while you are iterating over it mutably. Split iterating and modifing the image.

Comment: @hellow The crate is Piston's `image` crate.

Comment: A possible workaround is to have a loop over X and Y coordinates and use `get_pixel` and `put_pixel` functions instead of using `enumerate_pixels_mut`.

Comment: Your code don't make sense, you erase each time your previous value of pixel, please include a true [mcve] and the purpose of this code.

Comment: As @Stargateur mentioned, writing on `*pixel` a value that depends on pixels from the same image buffer will influence subsequent reads, and as such might not be what you want.